# Why SumProduct cannot use in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

**Scenario**

I am trying to use `COUNTIF` in my VBA code to count total how many similar string found in a range. But realised `COUNTIF` is not case sensitive. Eg: I want to count how many Apple in a range. But sometimes if in that range got apple, it is counting that also. Code as below. Consider `Range(poRange)` something like `C1:C100` and `Trim(mainpage.po.value)` as Apple

```
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(poRange), Trim(mainPage.po.Value))
```

Thus I decided to use another method which is

```
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(EXACT(Range(poRange), Trim(mainPage.po.Value))))
```

But this time I couldn't run my VBA due to Compile time error '`Sub or Function not defined`'

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Exact is not a native VBA function. That's why your code gets the function not defined error.

Comment: funny I was just about to look up what EXACT function was since I had never stumbled across it before in excel formulas.

Comment: What a relief to see a post with a specific question and attempted code. Thanks Anu - good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `EXACT` function, which `WorksheetFunction` does not expose.

For unexposed Excel functions, a common workaround is to convert the expression to a string and call the `Evaluate` function. A rudimentary routine would look like this:

```
Public Function SumProductExact(rng As Range, testItem As String) As Long
    Dim evalExpr As String

    On Error GoTo EH
    evalExpr = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(EXACT(" & rng.Address & ", """ & testItem & """)))"
    SumProductExact = Evaluate(evalExpr)
    Exit Function

EH:
    SumProductExact = -1
End Function
```

and would be called like so:

```
Debug.Print SumProductExact(Sheet1.Range("A1:A10"), "Apple")
```

But it hardly seems worth going to those lengths for a relatively trivial function, so you could just write your own `CountIf` function for an exact match. You might want to expand this to cater for other type comparisons, like dates, but fundamentally it would look like this:

```
Public Function CountIfExact(rng As Range, testItem As Variant) As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim c As Long

    On Error GoTo EH
    For Each v In rng.Value2
        If v = testItem Then c = c + 1
    Next

    CountIfExact = c
    Exit Function

EH:
    CountIfExact = -1
End Function
```

which would be called as follows:

```
Debug.Print CountIfExact(Sheet1.Range("A1:A10"), "Apple")
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I used the evaluate method and it works fine. Although I am curious why the formula is starting with `SumProduc`t!! `CountIf` makes more sense to understand what the formula doing

Comment: Quite right; `CountIf…` would be better. If you use the evaluate method, just be watchful of your unqualified range. If you're not using the active sheet then you might need to specify the worksheet name as part of the range definition.

Comment: Thanks. My case, I am using a dynamic range specified by some other part of program. So I guess I am safe about it. So far my program works well and testing didn't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

I used one of the above solutions and it solved the problem. Entire code as below

```
Public c As Integer

Sub findVal()
Call SumProductExact(Sheet1.Range("A1:A10"), "Apple")
MsgBox c ' You can use this c value for other calculations

End Sub

Public Function SumProductExact(rng As Range, testItem As String) As Long
    Dim evalExpr As String

    On Error GoTo EH
    evalExpr = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(EXACT(" & rng.Address & ", """ & testItem & """)))"
    SumProductExact = Evaluate(evalExpr)
    c = SumProductExact
    Exit Function

EH:
    SumProductExact = -1
End Function
```

Take note that for the above code, it is using static range which is A1:A10 and a static name Apple. You may change it to a dynamic range and name according to your needs.